# How do I combine these two queries into one query?

Tags: mysql, database

I know there are a lot of questions about this type of topic, but I can't find any that help with my problem.

I have two working queries.  I want to combine them into one query.  When I try to combine them, the data displayed is incorrect.  But, when they're seperate, the data is correct.

Query 1:

```
Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
concat('$', sum(a.amount)) as 'Total Paid'
From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
Where d.DonorId=p.DonorId
and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
group by d.donorid;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Donor        | Total Paid |
+--------------+------------+
| John Smith   | $3500.00   |
| Linda Smith  | $250.00    |
| Jack Clinton | $200.00    |
| Jane Doe     | $2100.00   |
+--------------+------------+
```

Query 2:

```
Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
concat('$', sum(a.amount)) as 'Pocket'
From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
Where (a.CompanyId is null) 
and d.DonorId=p.DonorId
and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
group by d.donorid;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+----------+
| Donor        | Pocket   |
+--------------+----------+
| John Smith   | $1750.00 |
| Linda Smith  | $100.00  |
| Jack Clinton | $200.00  |
| Jane Doe     | $2100.00 |
+--------------+----------+
```

When Combined:

```
Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor', 
concat('$', sum(a.amount)) as 'Total Paid',
concat('$', sum(a2.amount)) as 'Pocket'
From Donor d, Donor d2, Pledge p, Pledge p2, Payment a, Payment a2
where d.donorId=p.donorId
and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
and (a2.CompanyId is null)
and d2.DonorId = p2.DonorId
and p2.pledgeId = a2.PledgeId
group by d.DonorId;
```

Output:

```
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| Donor        | Total Paid | Pocket    |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
| John Smith   | $24500.00  | $20750.00 |
| Linda Smith  | $1750.00   | $12450.00 |
| Jack Clinton | $1400.00   | $8300.00  |
| Jane Doe     | $14700.00  | $8300.00  |
+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

Each of these queries has a column for Donor names and a column with some monetary values.  In my final query, I want a column with donor names, a column labeled 'Total Paid', and a column labeled 'Pocket'.  When I combine these two queries, the 'total paid' column gets all messed up as well as the 'pocket' column.

I know this might be difficult to help with without the table schema, but I figured I'd give it a shot.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
select
    'Donor',concat('$',sum('Total Paid')) as 'Total Paid',concat('$',sum('Pocket')) as 'Pocket'
from(
        Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
        sum(a.amount) as 'Total Paid', 0 as Pocket 
        From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
        Where d.DonorId=p.DonorId
        and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
        group by d.donorid

        union all

        Select Distinct concat(d.FirstName, ' ', d.LastName) as 'Donor',
        0 as 'Total Paid',sum(a.amount) as 'Pocket'
        From Donor d, Pledge p, Payment a
        Where (a.CompanyId is null) 
        and d.DonorId=p.DonorId
        and p.pledgeId = a.pledgeId
        group by d.donorid
    ) group by Donor;
```

Note: If you are using MySQL database, you should use `backticks`(" ` ") instead of single quotes for column names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  This almost works.  I get the proper output when I try the first sub query by itself and when I try the second subquery by itself.  But, when I try the whole thing, everything shows up as 0.  The column headings are correct, but all of the values are 0.  I have no idea why it would do this. Any suggestion on this issue?